# Does this way of sorting overwrite an existing list?

Tags: list, sorting

I'm costructing a graph and need to extract a subset of nodes based on two values assigned to them. Everything is stored as a list of lists, The test list looks like this:

inscribed_nodes = [[1, 168.0, 168.0], [2, 66.0, 148.0], [3, 91.0, 24.0], [4, 24.0, 48.0], [5, 126.0, 72.0], [6, 78.0, 75.0], [7, 70.0, 28.0], [8, 20.0, 49.0], [9, 30.0, 84.0]]

In a pattern of: [node_ID, first_value, second_value]

Now I perform two sortings, one for each value:

```
nodes_ascended_by_value1 = inscribed_nodes
nodes_ascended_by_value1.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
nodes_ascended_by_value1.reverse()

nodes_ascended_by_value2 = inscribed_nodes
nodes_ascended_by_value2.sort(key=lambda x: x[2])
nodes_ascended_by_value2.reverse()

print("v1 ",nodes_ascended_by_value1)
print("v2 ",nodes_ascended_by_value2)
```

This somehow prints nodes_ascended_by_value2 twice. Why?
I tried to save the lists as independent variables before prnting them and it still didn't work.

Comment: `nodes_ascended_by_value1 = inscribed_nodes` and the similar line for 2 doesn't make a copy. You're essentially sorting `inscribed_nodes` twice, then printing it twice. Make a copy of it if you want the other lists to act independently, or use `sorted` instead of `sort`.

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to python and only today thought of declaring new lists this way, I re-wrote all preexisting declarations like this from
new_list = []
for item in old_list:
   new_list.append(item)

Thanks again!